# rounding error of GNU C compiler

Tags: c, gcc

My textbook - C in a Nutshell, ISBN 978-0596006976

The part of casting, the code in an example showing C rounding error:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  long l_var = 123456789L;
  float f_var = l_var;

  printf("The rounding error (f_var - l_var) is %f\n", f_var - l_var);

  return 0;
}
```

then the value it output with nothing but 0.000000

seems it made no precision problem while casting those literal

with gcc(v4.4.7) command

```
gcc -Wall file.c -o exec
```

did GNU make a better way to get around the problem which mentioned in that chapter

or just some setting not strictly close to the issue of rounding error?

Comment: try to add `volatile` keyword to `l_var` and `f_var`

Comment: How are we supposed to know what problem is mentioned in the chapter?

Comment: Is this about the problem of enregistered variables secretly having a higher precision than floats stored in memory?

Comment: @ydroneaud: `volatile` is never the correct fix for issues like this. It's possible that GCC is ignoring the C standard and omitting the required drop of precision when assigning to a `float` object, but the correct fix for this is `-std=c99` or `-fexcess-precision=standard`. However I think OP's issue is something else entirely.

Comment: Either the book has an error, or C standard has changed since the publication. The idea of course is, that `f_var - l_var` would be evaluated as `(long)f_var - l_var` instead of `f_var - (float)l_var`.

Comment: @R.. is there a fix for code that address a broken use case ?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: The book has an error. The idea is not that the expression would be evaluated by converting `f_var` to `long`, but that the arithmetic would take place on a 387 fpu with excess precision, whereby the subtraction is evaluated in 80-bit `long double` precision, then rounded to `double` to pass to `printf`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what this chapter is telling you, but:

```
float f_var = l_var;
```

We can tell that `f_var` is `(float)l_var`. Now the expression:

```
f_var - l_var
```

As this operates on a `long` and a `float`, the `long` will be converted into a `float`. So the compiler will do:

```
f_var - (float)l_var
```

Which is the same as:

```
(float)l_var - (float)l_var
```

Which is zero, regardless of any rounding of the conversion.

Comment: Note that converting both to `long` or `double` before subtracting would be a way to fix this.

Comment: Actually, under `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`, I think that `f_var - l_var` is equivalent to `(long double)(float)l_var - (long double)l_var` and thus can evaluate to a nonzero result. But the simplest explanation is best, and your explanation works at least under `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 0`.

Comment: @Pascal I did't know about [FLT_EVAL_METHOD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD), thanks.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Actually I'm unclear on whether `FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2` would allow the equivalent of `(long double)f_var - (long double)l_var` or just `(long double)f_var - (long double)(float)l_var`.

Comment: @R.. A recent GCC seems to think that it is the latter: http://ideone.com/N0GEI5 (I have r172652 at home and it produces the same result with `gcc -mno-sse -mfpmath=387 -std=c99`. Compiling without optimization generates an ugly `fstps / flds` pair, as should separate compilation of a function for which the values are not available, but the GCC people have chosen an interpretation of the standard and are sticking to it, so that's good.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to this book.

My guess is that the example is trying to tell you that if you assign a 32 bit integer to a 32 bit float, you may lose bits due to truncation (rounding errors): [A 32 bit float has only 23 bit significand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) and some bits may be lost during the assignment accordingly.

Apparently, the example code is bogus in the book though. Here is the code to demonstrate the truncation error:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int32_t l_var = 123456789L;

  /* 32 bit variable, 23 bit significand, approx. 7 decimals  */
  float f_var = l_var; 

  double err = (double) f_var - (double) l_var;

  printf("The rounding error (f_var - l_var) is %f\n", err);

  return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
The rounding error (f_var - l_var) is 3.000000
```

on my machine.

Comment: I actually get `3.000000` with the example he posted.

Answer (score 0):

0 is the value you get if both values are converted to float, you'll get something else if they are converted to something else.  And there is an allowance in the standard to use wider floating point representation that required by the type for computation (*).  Using it here is especially tempting here as the result has to be converted to a double for passing to printf.

My version of gcc is not using that allowance when compiling for x86_64 (-m64 argument for gcc) and it is using it when compiling for x86 (-m32 argument).  That make sense when you know that for 64 bits, it is using sse instructions which can easily do the computation in float, while when compiling for 32 bits it is using the older "8087" stack model which can't do that easily.

---

(*) Last paragraph of 6.2.1.5 in C90, 6.3.1.8/2 in C99, 6.3.1.8/2 in C11.  I give the text of the latest (as in n1539)

> The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be
>   represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.

As pointed by Pascal Cuoq, starting from C99, you can test with [FLT_EVAL_METHOD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD).